# Why would you use private static inner class? Defeats the purpose of static inner class?

Tags: java, static, private, inner-classes

I've read all the articles I could find on static inner classes, and from what I understand:

- An instance of a static inner class can be created without previously creating the outer class. This is one main difference between static and non-static inner classes.

But none of the articles answer this question:

Why would you have a **private** static inner class, if the purpose of having a static inner class is so that you can create it without the outer class?

For example, Java's LinkedList implementation contains the `private static class Node<E>`. If we try instantiating `LinkedList<String>.Node<String>` it won't work since it's private. And I don't see why you would want to create a Node without a LinkedList either, since you just use the LinkedList's add() interface. So can't this just be a non-static inner class?

For me it seems like private and static for inner classes are contradictory, and if you want to be both private and static that's weird. So could someone please explain what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remember that an non-static nested class ("inner class") instance has a reference to its containing instance. That isn't free. If you don't need it, you shouldn't have it.

`LinkedList` is an excellent example of exactly why you'd have a `static` nested class: `LinkedList` needs multiple instances of `LinkedList.Node`, and it doesn't need those instances to have a reference to the list itself. That would be pointless overhead. So the `Node` class is `static` in order not to have those back references to the list. It's also `private` because it's only for internal use by `LinkedList`.

---

Side note on terminology: There is no "static inner class" in Java. If it's `static`, it's not an inner class, it's a static nested class. More in [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: I see! Thanks! So if I understand you correctly, the reason I mentioned for having static nested classes is just one out of multiple, with another being that it doesn't include references to the outer class, meaning it takes less space. So the LinkedList example we're choosing static not so we can create the Node without the LinkedList but so that the Nodes don't contain overhead. And we place the Node inside LinkedList for packaging purposes. Is that correct?

Comment: @MusicMap: Yup. You only use an inner class when the code in the inner class needs access to the containing class instance it's a part of. If the code in the nested class doesn't need access to the containing instance, use a static nested class instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a great explaination.